# Manage android fragment creation in an efficient way?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` inside which I have 4 tabs with `fragments`. Previously at app launch, it just loaded the two first `fragments` by default. Makes sense but problem was each time I navigated to 4th tab and got back to first tab, it had to get created again. To have my `fragments` get created just once, I used this method:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

So now the previous problem is gone and I can navigate through all the `fragments` without having them get created again. But the new problem is as the app is launched, all the `fragments` get created at once. And as I have network calls in each `fragment`, multiple network calls happen and this can cause problems (This is also not logical according to my app design). Now I need to find a way to solve the issue. Helps are appreciated.

**Edit:**

One solution is to use `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()` and place the network calls in there, as @Ferran offered. Sounds good! But I face another problem. When a `fragment` is selected in `onPageSelected(int position)`, all its view fields are null, despite I have defined them all in `onCreateView()` method (As all the `fragments` are created at app launch, these view fields shouldn't be null) and I cannot process the network call result and set data in the views.
I get `fragments` by this code:

```
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Note that the `fragment` object itself is not null.

Here is a typical of the fragments I have used:

public class TabFragmentPayment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private LinearLayout llError, llLoading, llNoItem;
private LinearLayout llPaymentRecords, llImageUpload;
private Button btnTryAgain; //here it just works for transaction get.
private RecyclerView rcv;
private ImageView ivPic, ivNationalCardPreview, ivSelect, ivAddAccount;
private TextView tvUploadPic, tvRequestPayment, tvNationalCardMessage;
private Spinner spBankAccounts;
private View view;
private ArrayList<Transaction> paymentRecordList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Bank> bankList = new ArrayList<>();
private long minToPay = -1;
public static boolean checkAccounts = false;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, null);
    setWidgetReferences();
    setClickListeners();
    setupActivity();
    return view;
}


private void setWidgetReferences() {
    ivPic = view.findViewById(R.id.ivfpPic);
    ivSelect = view.findViewById(R.id.ivfpSelect);
    ivAddAccount = view.findViewById(R.id.ivfpAddAccount);
    tvUploadPic = view.findViewById(R.id.tvfpUpload);
    tvRequestPayment = view.findViewById(R.id.tvfpRequestPayment);
    spBankAccounts = view.findViewById(R.id.spfpSelectAccount);
    llError = view.findViewById(R.id.llError);
    llLoading = view.findViewById(R.id.llLoading);
    llNoItem = view.findViewById(R.id.llNoItem);
    btnTryAgain = view.findViewById(R.id.btnReload);
    rcv = view.findViewById(R.id.rcvfpTransactions);
    ivNationalCardPreview = view.findViewById(R.id.ivfpNationalCardPreview);
    tvNationalCardMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvfpNationalCardMessage);
    llPaymentRecords = view.findViewById(R.id.llfpPayment);
    llImageUpload = view.findViewById(R.id.llfpImageUpload);
}

private void setClickListeners() {
    ivSelect.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivPic.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivAddAccount.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvUploadPic.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvRequestPayment.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(this);
}
}
```

And here is how I try to get the fragment in parent `Activity`:

```
@Override
 public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(position);
      if (fragment instanceof TabFragmentPayment) {
           TabFragmentPayment fr = (TabFragmentPayment) fragment;      
      }             
}
```

And the result fragment named fr has null view fields which is weird to me.

Comment: Please use this `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);` and check it

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all. 
`setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` tell the adapter to create 4 more pages while creating the first one. So, you can navigate through 5 pages without being reloaded. In your case, I think there's no need to use this.

To be sure your network calls are not being called on each creation, you can do it like this

Put your network call in a separate method on each fragment and make it public.

Then use this

```
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); 
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            // here you can call tour public fragment method
            // i = page index
            Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());
            // replace R.id.viewpager with your viewpager id
            // then call your public method
            ((YourFragmentClass)page).your_public_method();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

The first time, `onPageSelected` is not fired because the page was not selected but only created, but `onPageScrolled` does. So, play with these 2 methods to call your fragments methods.

Comment: I actually have put 3 in the method and it was a mistake in my question. By the way I got the same idea about managing network calls in onPageSelected() method, but I'm not sure if it's the only/best solution. Anyways thanks for the answer @Ferran

Comment: The only one surely not. The best, I don' t know, depends on how the rest of the code is structured and what you want to do within the logic of your application. More information would be needed in order to give more help.

Comment: I edited the question and added information @Ferran

Comment: Yes, I did @Ferran

Comment: Do not use `adapter.getItem(position)` to get the current fragment. This will surely create a new fragment. Try with `getSupportFragmentManager` like in my answer.

Comment: Well your code returns null. Actually I haven't set any tags in my fragment and as I am using a `viewpager`, I cannot do so.

Comment: My code must be used with a `viewpager`. You don't need to set tags. `FindFragmentByTag` is managed internally. You should replace the `R.id.viewpager` with the id of your `viewpager`, that used in `findViewById`. And in your case, replace `viewpager.getCurrentItem()` with `mViewPager.getCurrentItem()` or directly with `i` (should be the same). If this does not work, please, share your adapter.